# Providing links to files outside of IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an upload function in my system that stores the files on the d drive e.g D:\KBFiles.  Now i need to offer these files as links through internet explorer.  Obviously i cant just offer a path e.g D:\KBFiles\test.pdf.  Whats the best way to handle this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write "proxy" file with such code and call it `DownloadFile.aspx`:

```
string fileName = Request.QueryString["file"];
string filePath = Path.Combime("D:\\KBFile", fileName);
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

Then have such link:

```
<a href="DownloadFile.aspx?file=test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
```

This allows you to check the user permissions if you're using Login system and also you can check the requested file against some white list to prevent hacking attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Virtual Folder for that windows folder inside your WebApplication. As soon as IIS has mapped the virtual folder, it would be possible to use direct links, which would have your WebApplication as a root.